# nginx - how to reverse proxy everything, including directories and assets

Tags: proxy, nginx, reverse-proxy

We want to duplicate our website (yes, we are aware duplicated content). `domain-a.com` needs to be available also as `domain-b.com`.

My config looks like this:

```
server {

  listen 80;
  server_name www.domain-b.com;

  location / {
    autoindex off;
    proxy_buffering   off;
    # rewrite  (.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://104.25.206.103;  # Cloudflare
    proxy_set_header Host www.domain-a.com;
    proxy_redirect    default;

  }
}
```

This works for `www.domain-b.com/`. However `www.domain-b.com/info/about`is returning 503. Same for `/test.jpg`

How exactly can we proxy literally everything?

Comment: Why not just define an additional `server_name` or let it use the same root directory? If you get a 503 have you checked your logs to see what's actually happening?

Comment: that's not an option. needs to be "mirrored" and then also replaced a little content. 
serverlog actually is empty /access.log and /errors.log

Comment: If you don't see the error 500 in any of the logs chances are you're looking either at the wrong nginx logs or the wrong logs all together. That 500 might be thrown by your PHP engine or whatever is driving the original site so you should look into those logs as well.Iif you need to replace content how do you expect it to work by using a reverse proxy?

Comment: well, i did it myself now with Sinatra (Ruby). just take the incoming querystring, forward to the other server, replace some content in the body and return that body. easy game. 

mod_substitute would do the same on proxy level but since i'm a programmer and not a admin i stick to my app now

Comment: Do you expect this solution to be maintainable? I'd still suggest a fork or setting up proper configuration options and running an independent version. It would be way clearer but it's your application. You could try to write an answer based on what you did and accept it.

Comment: @Seth i've posted my answer :P

Answer (score 2):

The solution would have been:

```
server_name www.domain-a.com www.domain-b.org;
```

or just

```
server_name *;
```

plus this

```
proxy_set_header        Host $host;
```

which leaves it dynamic.

`503 Bad gateway` usually refers to a non-reachable upsteam server. Not necessarily something wrong with the config. Could also have been the wrong `X-Forwarded-Host` header from the `proxy_set_header` which was static and cloudflare declined serving it.

Answer (score 0):

my answer is a little different solution.

we ended up creating our own "proxy" based on ruby/sinatra, including cookie handling.

```
get /(.*)/ do
  if (asset? || download?) && !exception?
    return redirect to(target_url), 301
  end

  begin
    agent = Mechanize.new
    cookies.each.map{ |k,v| agent.cookie_jar << Mechanize::Cookie.new(name: k, value: v, domain: ".we.us", path: "/") }

    response = agent.get(target_url)

    cookies.clear
    agent.cookies.map{ |cookie| cookies[cookie.name] = cookie.value }

    content_type(response.response['content-type'])
    send("modify_#{target}", response.body)

  rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError
    p "throw a 404!"
    status 404
  end
end

def asset?
  # binding.pry
  extensions = %W(.jpg .png .gif .jpeg .ico .woff .ttf .gif .woff2 .cur)
  url = target_url
  url = url.split("?").first
  url.downcase.end_with?(*extensions)
end



def target_url
  target_host + query_string
end

def query_string
  # binding.pry
  #params['captures'].first
  if env["PATH_INFO"] == "/"
    "/"
  else
    env["REQUEST_URI"].scan(Regexp.new("#{env["PATH_INFO"]}.*")).first 
  end
end
```